# How to do basic AI

Tags: eclipse

I need some help in designing a simple AI for a tic tac toe game. I need the computer to place a 2 on the next available slot on his turn. It's for a beginner's eclipse programming class, but the professor has taken a sick leave and stopped answering questions! Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm having trouble with the method at the end ComputerInput[][].

```
package lab15;

public class WinnerCheck {

    public static int PL_ONE = 1;
    public static int PL_TWO = 2;
    static Console console = new Console();
    static final int PAUSE      = 500;

    public static int[][] b = { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean done = false;

        while (!done) {
            printBoard(b);
            playerOneInput();
            pause(PAUSE);
            detectWinner(b);
            console.clear();
        }
    }

    public static void pause(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }


    public static void placePiece(int[][] b, int r, int c, int player) {
        b[r][c] = player;
    }

    public static boolean isWinner(int[][] b, int player) {
        // check for a horizontal winner
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                if (b[i][j] == player
                    || b[j][i] == player ) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == b[i].length)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static int detectWinner(int[][] b) {
        if (isWinner(b, PL_ONE)) {
            return 1;
        } else if (isWinner(b, PL_TWO)) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void printBoard(int[][] b) {
        System.out.println("------");
        for (int[] row : b) {
            for (int element : row) {
                System.out.print(element + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("------");
        System.out.println("winner: " + detectWinner(b));
    }


    public static void playerOneInput() {
        switch (console.getKey()) {
        case '1':
            placePiece (b, 0, 0, 1);
            break;
        case '2':
            placePiece (b, 0, 1, 1);
            break;
        case '3':
            placePiece (b, 0, 2, 1);
            break;
        case '4':
            placePiece (b, 1, 0, 1);
            break;
        case '5':
            placePiece (b, 1, 1, 1);
            break;
        case '6':
            placePiece (b, 1, 2, 1);
            break;
        case '7':
            placePiece (b, 2, 0, 1);
            break;
    case '8':
            placePiece (b, 2, 1, 1);
            break;
    case '9':
            placePiece (b, 2, 2, 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    public static int computerInput(int[][]b) {
        int a[] = {-1, -1};
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                if (b(0)) {

                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to check if b[i,j] is equal to 0. If it is then put a 2 in and return

Comment: I tried it using this code, but I get an error in a[0] = a[1]


\ public static int computerInput(int[][]b) {

 int a[]= {-1};

  for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {

  for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length;j++) {

   if (b[i][j] == 0

    || b[i][j] == 1 ) {
     a[0] = a[1];
    }
    }
  }
  return a[];
 } 
}